# Split large JSON file into smaller files

Tags: python, json, linux, shell

I have a need to split very large  json file (20GB) into multiple smaller json files (Say threshold is 100 MB).

The Example file layout looks like this.

file.json

```
[{"name":"Joe", "Place":"Denver", "phone_number":["980283", "980284", "980285"]},{"name":"kruger", "Place":"boston",
 "phone_number":["980281", "980282", "980283"]},{"name":"Dan", "Place":"Texas","phone_number":["980286", "980287", "980286"]}, {"name":"Kyle", "Place":"Newyork", "phone_number":["980282", "980288", "980289"]}]
```

The output should look like this

file1:

```
[{"name":"Joe", "Place":"Denver", "phone_number":["980283", "980284", "980285"]}, {"name":"kruger", "Place":"boston", "phone_number":["980281", "980282", "980283"]}]
```

file2:

```
[{"name":"Dan", "Place":"Texas","phone_number":["980286", "980287", "980286"]}, {"name":"Kyle", "Place":"Newyork", "phone_number":["980282", "980288", "980289"]}]
```

May I know the best way to achieve this? Should i opt for shell command or python?

Comment: Using pyspark will a better approach in this situation i guess. It will give ability to make partitions out of Single data. You can specify number partition when doing so.

Comment: You'll undoubtedly run into memory issues if you try to read the entire file into memory with Python, but you also won't be able to pipe the file in a shell script. You might want to buffer it somehow.

Comment: I'd use a language with a streaming json parser available. Definitely not shell.

Comment: Is the json file always structured that way: 1 line per item? If so, you can just remove the first `[` and the final `,` and `]` for each line. `sed` and `awk` can do that without loading the whole file in memory.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, Yes the input json file is always structured that way, list of json records.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, Sorry for the confusion, It is not always 1 line per item. The json record can be too big  with many more fields (other than the fields, i  posted)and one record can span across multiple lines. I have edited the example to be more clear

Comment: @kites Ok, sad. `awk` can be used in bash instead of `sed` to do the brackets/parenthesis/braces matching and it should be pretty fast. That being said, the answer of JimmyNJ should be more user-friendly/simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The Python module `json-stream` can do this, with a few caveats, which I'll get to later.

You'll have to implement the visitor pattern.

```
import json_stream

def visitor(item, path):
    print(f"{item} at path {path}")

with open('mylargejsonfile.json','r') as f:
    json_stream.visit(f, visitor)
```

This `visitor` function will get called for each complete JSON element encountered in a depth-first manner. So, each complete JSON element (number, string, array, etc) will invoke this callback. It is up to you at which point to pause processing and write your partial file out.

Things to look out for include if your input file is a single JSON element (like a single dictionary) you will have to change the output structure if you want the split-up files to also be valid JSON.

An illustrative example of this would be to try to split this JSON file
`{ "top" : [1,2,3] }` into two separate files of half the size. You can't without changing the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file is structured that way with 1 item per line and no item in the main list that are a sub-list, you you just do a basic string replacement with `sed`. This is fragile, but relatively fast and memory efficient since `sed` is designed for streaming text.

Here is an example modifying "file.json" in-place:

```bash
sed -e 's/^\[//g' -e 's/, *$//g' -e 's/\]$//g' -i file.json
```

Then each line can be written in a separate file using a basic bash loop using `read`.

To compute the input file without modifying it and write the target files, you can do that:

```bash
i=1
sed -e 's/^\[//g' -e 's/, *$//g' -e 's/\]$//g' file.json | while read -r line; do
    echo -e "[$line]" > file$i
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

For the example file, it creates two files: `file1` and `file2`